# БД для хранения информации для мобильного приложения

Tags: база-данных

У меня вопрос. Разрабатываем приложение для английского языка. Где лучше всего хранить информацию по заданиям?
То есть будет реализовано что-то типо теста с выбором ответа. Тест из n количества вопросов (n > 100)
Можно ли использовать для этого БД и если да, то в каном виде хранить там информацию?
До этого БД использовал только как структуру для хранения пользователей, где информации не так много.

Comment: Сотня вопросов - это немного. БД - самый подходящий вариант хранения. Хранить информацию, вероятно, надо в 2 таблицах - в одной вопросы, в другой ответы со ссылкой на вопрос и признаком правильного ответа.

Comment: " если да, то в каном виде хранить там информацию?" - Вообще говоря, проектирование БД - это очень обширная тема. У вас явно просматриваются следующие сущности: пользователь, попытка прохождения теста, тест, вопрос, ответ. По таблице на сущность. Плюс связи, ограничения целостности и прочее. Потом, когда это сделаете, обязательно захочется каких-нибудь дополнительных рюшечек навесить. Слишком широкий вопрос.